# Intro screen is not opening

Tags: android, android-manifest

We decided to make an intro/welcome screen to our app. The activity called Welcome Activity needs to be launched when user goes to the application for the first time. All other times Main Activity needs to be launched. That's how I've done it in Android Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.ocrreader"
android:installLocation="auto">

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<application
    android:name=".OcrApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:fullBackupContent="false"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="Ingredient analysis"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.vision.DEPENDENCIES"
        android:value="ocr" />
    <activity android:name=".WelcomeActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"
        android:exported="true"
        >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".OcrCaptureActivity"
        android:label="Read Text" />
    <activity android:name=".ListResult" />
    <activity android:name=".AllIngredients" />
    <activity android:name=".IngredientDescription" />
    <activity android:name=".Instruction" />
</application>
```

Is it a problem in my Manifest file or in the Welcome Activity code? I've used SharedPreferences in my onCreate. I have a class prefmanager

```
public class PrefManager {
    SharedPreferences pref;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    Context _context;

    // shared pref mode
    int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

    // Shared preferences file name
    private static final String PREF_NAME = "androidhive-welcome";

    private static final String IS_FIRST_TIME_LAUNCH = "IsFirstTimeLaunch";

    public PrefManager(Context context) {
        this._context = context;
        pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
        editor = pref.edit();
    }

    public void setFirstTimeLaunch(boolean isFirstTime) {
        editor.putBoolean(IS_FIRST_TIME_LAUNCH, isFirstTime);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public boolean isFirstTimeLaunch() {
        return pref.getBoolean(IS_FIRST_TIME_LAUNCH, true);
    }

}
```

On create

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Checking for first time launch - before calling setContentView()
    prefManager = new PrefManager(this);
    if (!prefManager.isFirstTimeLaunch()) {
        launchHomeScreen();
        finish();
    }

    // Making notification bar transparent
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    dotsLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutDots);
    btnSkip = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_skip);
    btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_next);


    // layouts of all welcome sliders
    // add few more layouts if you want
    layouts = new int[]{
            R.layout.welcome_slide1,
            R.layout.welcome_slide2,
            };

    // adding bottom dots
    addBottomDots(0);

    // making notification bar transparent
    changeStatusBarColor();

    myViewPagerAdapter = new MyViewPagerAdapter();
    viewPager.setAdapter(myViewPagerAdapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(viewPagerPageChangeListener);

    btnSkip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            launchHomeScreen();
        }
    });

    btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // checking for last page
            // if last page home screen will be launched
            int current = getItem(+1);
            if (current < layouts.length) {
                // move to next screen
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(current);
            } else {
                launchHomeScreen();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: can you update your question with `oncreate` code in `WelcomeActivity`?

Comment: can you provide you `WelcomeActivity` oncreate code, your menifest file seems to be okay may be problem in `WelcomeActivity` code.

Comment: I added the code you had asked for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, its working...

I have create Shared Preference in Main Activity and checked it in Welcome Activity.

If it run first time, then not found any Shared Preference and will Do Anything on Welcome Activity.

If it run second or more times, it found Shared Preference then redirect to Main Activity without launch Welcome Activity.

1. In Welcome Activity, onCreate method -

> ```
> if ((getSharedPreferences("Demo", MODE_PRIVATE).contains("value"))){
>         Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
>         startActivity(intent);
>         finish();
>     }
>     
>     else {
>         new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
>             @Override
>             public void run() {
>                 Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
>                 startActivity(intent);
>                 finish();
>             }
>         },5000);
>     }
> ```

2. In Main Activity, onCreate method -

> ```
> SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("Demo",MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
>     editor.putString("value", "1");
>     editor.apply();
> ```

3. Manifest file -

> ```
> <activity android:name=".WelcomeActivity">
>         <intent-filter>
>             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
>             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
>         </intent-filter>
>     </activity>
>
>     <activity android:name=".MainActivity"></activity>
> ```

Comment: Main2Activity --> Activity which we want open after WelcomeActivity

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever call `setFirstTimeLaunch(false)` before? If not, that's because you return `true` as a default value in your function:

```
public boolean isFirstTimeLaunch() {
    return pref.getBoolean(IS_FIRST_TIME_LAUNCH, true);
}
```

Try to change it to `return pref.getBoolean(IS_FIRST_TIME_LAUNCH, false)` and don't forget to `setFirstTimeLaunch(true)`. My suggestion is to add it to this:

```
if (!prefManager.isFirstTimeLaunch()) {
    prefManager.setFirstTimeLaunch(true); // Add this
    launchHomeScreen();
    finish();
}
```